# Creating multiple hyperlinks in attribute table on relative paths

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.6, hyperlink

I got the task to create a layer with multiple hyperlinks within the attribute table. One link should go to the PDF document, that describes the feature further. The other link should go to one, or multiple pictures of the same feature. I would like to have only one field for all pictures.

Is it possible to create one hyperlink to multiple pictures? I will have to create hyperlinks for around 500 features, so the Option to create hyperlinks manually is not suitable.

My second problem is the fact, that I have to use relative paths for the hyperlinks.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.6 and QGIS 3.4 so if there is a solution within QGIS with a product, that works in ArcGIS as well, I would be happy with that too.

Comment: Normally for situations like this the hyperlink points to a file directory, which means the directory structure needs to group pictures in ways that make sense for your features.  If your pictures are in a document management system and one of the fields for classifying the documents holds your FID or a value that would return all the related photos, you can build a query that returns links to all the documents.  For example, all recorded map, environmental constraint sheet, certificate of correction, corner record and tie book docs have a tract field I can query to give a list of links.

Comment: To make a solution that's compatible with both QGIS and ArcGIS, store the filepath in a text field. In QGIS you can set up the field widget to interpret the filepath as a link. Presumably in ArcGIS there's a similar solution.

Comment: In the main ArcMap options there is a setting that will interpret any text value that is formatted as a hyperlink to be a hyperlink in the Identify tool, Attribute window and possibly other data views.  I think it may be set by default.  I think this behavior is also the default in ArcGIS Online map popups.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will look into your suggestion. But until now, it was possible to create hyperlinks to a complete path, but not to a relative path. As soon as I have further insights in this topic I will write again.